# How to get a returned value to another function in C#.net?

Tags: .net, return

I have a Windows Form that calculates and displays the `tax amount` and the `net salary.`

- The function `CalTax (double sal, double taxper)` that **returns the tax amount** which is calculated from the gross salary.
- The function `CalNetSal (double sal, double tax)` is used to **return the net salary.**
- The `taxAmt` value calculated in `CalTax()` needs to be passed to the `CalNetSal()` in order to calculate the `net salary.`
- Results of the two functions should be displayed in two labels.

Note:All inputs and output must be handled only inside the buttons.

How do I pass the `taxAmt` to the `CalNetSal()` function?

And how do I display the results of both functions into two labels, `lblTaxAmt` and `lblNetSal`?
Here's the code I tried,

```
    public double CalTax(double sal, double taxper)
    {
        double taxAmt=0;
        taxAmt = sal * (taxper / 100);
        return taxAmt;
    }
    public double CalNetSal(double sal, double tax)
    {       
        double netSal = 0;
        netSal = sal - tax;
        return netSal;
    }
    private void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double gs = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrossSal.Text);
        double tp = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxP.Text);
   
        lblTaxAmt.Text = CalTax(gs, tp).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Just make global variables, and you can use it everywhere you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of calculated tax into a variable, and then calculate the net salary, and finally update both labels in once. Like this:

```
        public double CalTax(double sal, double taxper)
        {
            double taxAmt = 0;
            taxAmt = sal * (taxper / 100);
            return taxAmt;
        }
        public double CalNetSal(double sal, double tax)
        {
            double netSal = 0;
            netSal = sal - tax;
            return netSal;
        }
        private void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double gs = Convert.ToDouble(txtGrossSal.Text);
            double tp = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxP.Text);

            double taxAmt = CalTax(gs, tp);
            double netSal = CalNetSal(gs, taxAmt);
            lblTaxAmt.Text = taxAmt.ToString();
            lblNetSal.Text = netSal.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Wrap those `Convert.ToDouble()` calls in a `Try/Catch` block, or use [Double.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead.  This way your program doesn't crash when something other than a double is entered into the TextBoxes.